# Unable to acces sound settings

Tags: sound, system-settings

I’m unable to access the sound settings in U1404 TT. Before updating to Ubuntu 14.04, with right click and System setting I had access to some settings which allowed me to set different sound levels for different application. Now I'm unable to do that. Click on Sound settings send me to a Setting window where sound settings are not available.

Actually, as you can see, my system settings menu is quite reduced (no options for keyboard).

[image: The settings windows which appears after right click on the sound indicator and click on sound settings]

[image: This is the windows and the tag I can't find no more]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot please.

Comment: Try with instaling the sound card drivers and alsa packages `sudo apt-get install alsa-base alsa-base-udeb alsa-firmware-loaders alsa-oss alsa-source alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui alsa-utils alsa-utils-udeb alsamixergui`

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package alsa-base-udeb
E: Unable to locate package alsa-utils-udeb
dumitru@dumitru-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ ^C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to software center. Search for `control center`. Select Sound and anyother parts you thing are missing.
[image]